# Cerrar dibujo de Tabla python

Tags: python

estoy dibujando una tabla mediante ascii, la cual no se cierra bien mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', db='stack',password='toor')
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute("select * from test;")
res = c.fetchall()


print("╔═════╦══════════════════╗")
print("║ ID  ║ NOMBRE           ║")
print("╠═════╬══════════════════╣")
print("║     ║                  ║")
for id, name in res:
  print '║  '+str(id)+ '  ║' + str(name) + '             ║'
print '╚═════╩══════════════════╝  '
```

mi resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que se cierre completamente la tabla, pero nose porque no lo hace incluso pensé que era por espacios existentes en la BD en el name pero no existe, agradezco cualquier sugerencia..!!

Comment: No se si conocés esto: https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate. Es muy fácil de usar y ya contempla problemas como el tuyo. Saludos.

Comment: esta vacansisimo lo voy a revisar @PatricioMoracho gracias..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diego, el problema es que los nombres tendrán diferente largo y, por lo tanto, los espacios a la derecha dependerán de qué tan largo es el nombre.

Se me ocurre que lo más sencillo es definir un ancho para cada columna y trabajar sobre estos valores:

```
test = ((1, 'Diego'), (2, 'Fernanda'), (10, 'Cesar'), (100, 'Ignacio'))
column_id_space = 7
column_name_space = 20

print('╔%s╦%s╗' % ('═' * column_id_space, '═' * column_name_space))
print('║%s║%s║' % (' ID'.ljust(column_id_space), ' NOMBRE'.ljust(column_name_space)))
print('╠%s╬%s╣' % ('═' * column_id_space, '═' * column_name_space))
for id, name in test:
  print '║%s║%s║' % ((' %s' % str(id)).ljust(column_id_space), (' %s' % name).ljust(column_name_space))
print('╚%s╩%s╝' % ('═' * column_id_space, '═' * column_name_space))
```

En el script, he definido un ancho para cada columna de tal manera que sea una constante, haciendo uso de `str.ljust` puedes alinear el texto haciendo uso de los espacios definidos. El resultado:

```
╔═══════╦════════════════════╗
║ ID    ║ NOMBRE             ║
╠═══════╬════════════════════╣
║ 1     ║ Diego              ║
║ 2     ║ Fernanda           ║
║ 10    ║ Cesar              ║
║ 100   ║ Ignacio            ║
╚═══════╩════════════════════╝
```

Si juegas con los valores de los anchos, por ejemplo 20 y 40, va cambiando la forma en que se ve el resultado:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID                 ║ NOMBRE                                 ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1                  ║ Diego                                  ║
║ 2                  ║ Fernanda                               ║
║ 10                 ║ Cesar                                  ║
║ 100                ║ Ignacio                                ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Genial, aun recuerdo como era las epocas del buen pascal y su GOTOXY.. y listo.... funcionó bien gracias..!!